# How to SELECT rows with MAX(column value), distinct with another column AND TABLE?

Tags: sql, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

I know there was [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql) asking how to select max of one column distinct with another column. However, I need code which selects max of one column distinct with another column *and another table*.

All the examples creating a `t1` and `t2` do not work if you have a second table you have to input in the from.  For example:

```
Colors (Table 1): Pigments (Column 1), Lights (Column 2)

Time (Table 2): Hour (Column 1), Minute (Column 2)
```

So, if I wanted to get the `Max()` `Hour` for only `Pigments`, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  What is the relationship between the two tables?

Comment: I think you'd better to add a FK to colors: `Colors(Pigments, Lights, TIME_ID REFERENCES Time); Time(id, hour, minute)`